# Does windows 7 have xp virutalization built in or do I need virtualPC?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, virtualization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [does windows7 come with something like virtualpc built in?](https://superuser.com/questions/21779/does-windows7-come-with-something-like-virtualpc-built-in)

Does windows7 have xp virutalization built in or do I need virtualPC?

Comment: This is a duplicate.

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/21779/does-windows7-come-with-something-like-virtualpc-built-in

Answer (score 2):

You need to download the [XP Mode RC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx).

Comment: how is that different that me downloading virtualPC and installing winxp? is it different in some way?

Comment: XP Mode doesn't require a licensed version of XP that you would need to install XP in VirtualPC.  VirtualPC might give you better support since it is closed to a true install of XP.  It depends on your application needs and if you have/can afford a separate copy of XP.

Answer (score 2):

You need to download it, and it's only available for Professional and Ultimate editions.

From the [Windows 7 website](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/features/whats-new-work.aspx?tab=2):

> With Windows 7 Professional or Ultimate, you’ll be able to run many
>   productivity and business programs
>   designed for Windows XP. Some
>   additional software will be necessary
>   and it will be available
>   free-of-charge as a download from
>   Microsoft.