# Windows 7 virtually running Windows XP

Tags: windows-7, virtualization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [does windows7 come with something like virtualpc built in?](https://superuser.com/questions/21779/does-windows7-come-with-something-like-virtualpc-built-in)

I heard you can somehow run a (virtual) Windows xp from within Windows 7

Anyone knows how to do it?

Specifically I want to install a program as if it was installed in windows xp, but use it from windows 7... or maybe I misunderstood something about this feature

Comment: this is a dupicate.

Comment: couldn't find another... do you have a link?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/21779/does-windows7-come-with-something-like-virtualpc-built-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Windows XP Mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx)
This does exactly what you want

You need a CPU with virtualization extensions

Comment: If the CPU does not support virtualization, there's not way to do it?

Comment: You also need to be running something higher than Home Premium in order to have access to Windows XP mode.  And it'll be no use for 3d games.

Comment: Juan, you could install VirtualBox or VMWare or some other such, and install Windows XP inside of that.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation would be to install [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) and install Windows XP on that. It's the best and most error-proof solution I know of.